# how track sessionID for shopping cart table in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, session

I'm using php laravel 5.2 for my project. I want to design shopping cart with database table(table name is cart). cart table has column name session_id to determine each users cart.

the problems are:

1. when user logged in session id will change and I lose cart for that user(and other conditions that sessionId will change).
2. when session expired shopping cart still exist in database also it is not been use any more, how can I figure this out and delete these kind of carts?

or any other idea for shopping cart design with database?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is really no reason to use the session ID as the identifier for the cart owner. The logic behind handling a shopping cart is pretty simple and it equates to the following:

- When a user that is not logged in (let's call it a **guest**) visits your website, a session is created automatically by Laravel.
- If that guest user adds something to the cart, then the item/product added to the cart will be stored in the session. There's no reason to store the cart information for a guest in the database because that session is transient and is only needed while the guest is active on your website. Once that guest user leaves the site (i.e. the browser closes or the session expires) there's nothing you can do (realistically) to identify the same user if he ever comes back (hence the term used is **guest**). If you'd like to allow guests to place orders you can use the session cart info to place the order (still no database is needed for guests).
- It only makes sense to store cart information in the database (your `cart` table) when you're dealing with a **registered** user that has **logged in**. And in that case, the identifier that links the cart items to the user is the `user_id`, since a user can only have one cart. So the `cart` table can be as simple as:

```
+---------+------------+
| user_id | product_id |
+---------+------------+
```

- storing the `user_id` and `product_id` is really all you basically need to handle a cart item, since it's just a list that references a user for whom the details are stored in the `users` table and a product for which the details are stored in the `products` table.

Of course when a guest user adds some items to the cart (which at this point is stored in the session), if that guest decides to log in while having stuff in the session cart, it might makes sense to add (more exactly sync) those items with the database once the login process is successful.

So if the user had already some products in the database cart from the last time he/she was logged in, then the new products from the current session cart will be added to the old ones. Although it's your choice if you want to sync the items or just override them altogether to keep only the new cart items.

---

So following the above guidelines removes the need to delete cart items from the database, because there will only ever be cart items in the database that are linked to registered users that need to stay there to be available the next time those users log in.

Comment: When the user adds a product to the cart, they should be able to close the browser session and revisit the website few days after and still see the items in the basket. It makes sense to use cookies instead, but also persist the carts to the DB, as it gives valuable statistics such as what products are often selected, and are thus popular.

Answer (score 0):

You could rely on Cookies:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/requests#cookies

Or even better a shopping cart package made for laravel:

https://github.com/Crinsane/LaravelShoppingcart

This package I use in my Laravel 5 ecommerce implementations.

Comment: It seems to be a nice package.